# Error raster file seems to not exist in R

Tags: r

I have reinstalled R because of disfunction of pgirmess package. I have re-downloaded all necessary packages. I have used the same script that works fine before re-installation. However I cant read raster objects and I obtain a message:

```
Error: file.exists(filename) is not TRUE
```

but I know that these files exist!

If I am running {raster} exemple

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
r <- raster(f)
```

{raster} and R works fine. Any help? I cant really imagine where the problem could be! (I have verified a working directory, check file existence in different program, restarted R and computer, tried to read different rasters from different directories...). When I try to read tables, it works fine. Only raster files are problematic. Thank you really much

How it looks in R:

```
> getwd()                                               # where am I working?
[1] "D:/UEL/Data/2014_05_21 classify final/indexy"
> file.exists("n_msi2011.img")                          # does file exist?
[1] TRUE
> a<-raster("D:/UEL/Data/2014_05_21 classify final/indexy/n_msi2011.img") # read    
                                                                          # existing  
                                                                          # file
Error: file.exists(filename) is not TRUE                # why???
```

Comment: Debug `raster` to see what exactly `filename` is, and what goes wrong.

Comment: Probably need to escape the spaces in the file name, as the quotes may get stripped along the way.  Strongly recommend you give the file a more sensible name.  Besides, if you're in that directory, why are you giving the full pathname? just supply the file name!

Comment: I really try.. for filename you can find only: Get the filename of a Raster* object. I know that raster object exist (check as file.exists) and has its filename. What else can be hide behind "debug raster"? Every help will be greately appreciated

Comment: Hi @Carl Witthoft, I have replaced spaces by _ in directory path, and I have used more straighforward approach as a<-raster("n_msi2011.img"), I have also simplified raster name (-> msi2011). None of this doesnt seem to work. Maybe there is different solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was in not well updated {sp} package. After its reinstallation and then updating {raster} pkg the problem was fixed.

**Recommendation for the futur reinstalation of R (Win7):**

1. uninstall R (Start->Control Panel-> Uninstall a Program)
2. install new R version
3. from directory of your previous R version (C:/Program Files/.../R/R-3.0.2) copy all
   packages in /R/R-3.0.2/Library (R keep all your previous installations)
4. paste copied packages into new created R version R/R-3.1.1/Library
5. run new R
6. insert in R console:`update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`

and it has to work!

Comment: No need to reboot. That's an urban legend perpetuated by incompetent IT staffers world around.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It went away after I installed and loaded the package `rgdal`

See code below:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
object <- raster("object.img")
```