# Raster and file does not exist

Tags: r, raster

I'm completely lost on this as the file exists in the directory and my previous code has worked fine.  But for whatever reason I'm getting this error:

```
Error: file.exists(filename) is not TRUE
```

I found [a question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713312/error-raster-file-seems-to-not-exist-in-r) but it didn't work.

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0lfuv14mrc0r94/PRISM_tmin_stable_4kmM2_189501_bil.bil?dl=0)

Code :

```
library(raster)
r1 = raster("/.../PRISM_tmin_stable_4kmM2_189501_bil.bil")
```

Any suggestions why this is giving me file does not exist?

Comment: Is `/.../` really part of the code or you shortened the path for the example?

Comment: Shortened for directory path....it's not part of the path

Comment: @Pascal I've opened *.bil files in a single directory before without a problem....

Comment: I cannot open your file with `raster`. I guess something is missing.

Comment: @Pascal Yes I think you are correct, but now i'm getting some errors when install rgdal....so I'm working on that....i'll update soon

Comment: Start by running `file.exists()` on its own to debug path or permissions problems.  Then move on to `raster` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pascal pointed out, the *.hdr files need to be included in the directory of the *.bil file.  Then the raster object can be loaded.